# Joining CSV data with a polygon Layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a CSV file with 800 rows and 20 columns that I would like to join with a shapefile (polygon) that has only 10 rows and 1 column (Id).

How should I go about this?

Comment: you need to create a join field. a field in both data sources that can be tied together.

Comment: Based on your tag of QGIS, here's a tutorial for doing a table join in QGIS: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: Is this a one:many (1:m) join, in which you would expect the 10 rows in the shapefile to match up with one or more of the 800 rows in the CSV? Or do you only expect 10 rows from the CSV to match with 10 rows from the shapefile?

Comment: as long as they both data sets have lat long just convert the csv to a shapefile and use the join function in QGIS, there is also an option to convert CSV to a shapefile, I believe.

Comment: If you do not have lat/lon in your csv, this might be doable with a virtual layer. After you import your csv as table, use the create virtual layer form and write the sql query to join both layers together.

Comment: The csv file contain field data from random sites across a country, whereas the polygon have the ID column for the 10 subcounties within the country. Also,the csv data have both  lat long data sets, however, when I covert it to a shapefile and  join with the polygon layer, all the 20 columns  are added with 10 empty rows.

Comment: Then this is a case of spatial joining. I suggest using _Add polygon attributes to points_ in the SAGA Processing toolbox to add the subcounty ID to your field data layer.